# Xamarin IOS Native Linking Failed in `CNPPopupController`

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am working on Microsoft Xamarin IOS Project (C#) which is using `CNPPopupControllerSharp` for the popup.
I am facing some issues with `CNPPopupControllerDelegate` reference. Every time when i build the project we are getting below error related with Native linking.

Attaching error screenshot

[image]

Comment: Did you use Objective Sharpie to bind the native ios package?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT No..